# ng cli new command : use node_modules from parent directory

Tags: node-modules, angular-cli-v6

Is there a way to skip downloading node_modules all over again and use the node_modules in the parent directory when using ng new command? This will expedite the new project template generation over slow internet connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an option to skip install the npm packages by using ng new myProject --skip-install.